# How to parse json data in Python?

Tags: python, json

Please help me to parse this json in python.

```
{ "IT" : [   
                            { "firstName" : "ajay",  
                              "lastName"  : "stha",
                              "age"       : 24 },

                            { "firstName" : "Michiel",  
                              "lastName"  : "Og",
                              "age"       : 35 }
                          ],                            
          "sales"       : [ 
                            { "firstName" : "Guru", 
                              "lastName"  : "red",
                              "age"       : 27 },

                            { "firstName" : "Jim",   
                              "lastName"  : "Galley",
                              "age"       : 34 }
                          ] 
        }
```

How to parse this json in Python?Please help me

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html should provide you all the information you need

Comment: -1 for failing to do a simple Google search before posting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
What the problem with you?I got problem and ask.do you have any problem with this?

Answer (score 5):

Using [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
data = json.loads(stringinput)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
jsonResponse = json.loads(data)
jsonDataSales = jsonResponse["sales"]
jsonDataIt = jsonResponse["IT"]
it_first_name_list = []
it_last_name_list = []
it_age_list = []
sales_first_name_list = []
sales_last_name_list = []
sales_age_list = []

for item in jsonDataIt:
    it_first_name_list.append(item.get("firstName"))
    it_last_name_list.append(item.get("lastName"))
    it_age_list.append(item.get("age"))

for item in jsonDataSales:
    sales_first_name_list.append(item.get("firstName"))
    sales_last_name_list.append(item.get("lastName"))
    sales_age_list.append(item.get("age"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary with nested structures is very similar to JSON data,
though Python’s variables and expressions support richer structuring options (any part
of the following can be an arbitrary expression in Python code) for eg.

```
>>> name = dict(first='Bob', last='Smith')
>>> rec = dict(name=name, job=['dev', 'mgr'], age=40.5)
>>> rec
{'job': ['dev', 'mgr'], 'name': {'last': 'Smith', 'first': 'Bob'}, 'age': 40.5}
```

The final dictionary format displayed here is a valid literal in Python code, and almost
passes for JSON when printed as is, but the json module makes the translation official
—here translating Python objects to and from a JSON serialized string representation
in memory:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(rec)
'{"job": ["dev", "mgr"], "name": {"last": "Smith", "first": "Bob"}, "age": 40.5}'
>>> S = json.dumps(rec)
>>> S
'{"job": ["dev", "mgr"], "name": {"last": "Smith", "first": "Bob"}, "age": 40.5}'
>>> O = json.loads(S)
>>> O
{'job': ['dev', 'mgr'], 'name': {'last': 'Smith', 'first': 'Bob'}, 'age': 40.5}
>>> O == rec
True
```

It’s similarly straightforward to translate Python objects to and from JSON data strings
in files. Prior to being stored in a file, your data is simply Python objects; the JSON
module recreates them from the JSON textual representation when it loads it from the
file:

```
>>> json.dump(rec, fp=open('testjson.txt', 'w'), indent=4)
>>> print(open('testjson.txt').read())
{
"job": [
"dev",
"mgr"
],
"name": {
"last": "Smith",
"first": "Bob"
},
"age": 40.5
}
>>> P = json.load(open('testjson.txt'))
>>> P
{'job': ['dev', 'mgr'], 'name': {'last': 'Smith', 'first': 'Bob'}, 'age': 40.5}
```

Comment: @backcross if you find it useful then please mark this answer as right so that others can get benefited.