# How to parse pickle dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with a dictionary. From different resources, I understood that is comfortable to use pickle. I want to use pickle to save triples like: **`subject: predicate: object`**, but later I want to load them and fill an array
Assuming, my code:

```
import pickle

file_name = 'fna.txt'

class DictClass:
    def __init__(self, subj, predicate, obj ):
        self.subj = subj
        self.predicate = predicate
        self.obj = obj
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'DictClass(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.subj, self.predicate, self.obj)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.subj == other.subj) and (self.predicate == other.predicate) and (self.obj == other.obj)

data = {'triple': DictClass(17,'subClassOf', 34), 'triple': DictClass(22,'subClassOf', 44)}

print('data:', data)
print('repr(data):', repr(data))
print("data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass})?:", data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass}))

# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.  
def ld_dict(fname):
    reader = pickle.load(open(fname, 'rb'))
    print(reader)
    return True

# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
def sv_dict(fname):
    pickle.dump( data, open( fname, "wb" ) )
    return True

if(sv_dict(file_name)):
    print('File saved!')

if(ld_dict(file_name)):
    print('File loaded!')
```

In generally, I want to save data in the dictionary and later load it and make some processing about it but I have a problem. I cannot access to the information into the loaded data. In function `ld_dict` I was trying to read information and have results:

```
data: {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
repr(data): {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass})?: True
File saved!
triple
File loaded!
```

How I can get information in the way like, for example, JSON. How to parse JSON I found here([How to parse json data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033511/how-to-parse-json-data-in-python)). Also, I have seen this resource: [how to save a dictionary in pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063306/how-to-save-a-dictionary-in-pickle) Thank you for help

Comment: So you want to use `json` instead of `pickle`?

Comment: I would use pickle but when I don't it I will see JSON

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not at all clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Because you open your files inside the loops, they will only store the last entry in your data dict().  Open your file prior to entering your loops and close it after.

Comment: data is also overwriting the 'triple' key with it's second entry, so it only has 1 entry

Comment: Don't use a loop to save your dict.  Just save it: pickle.dump(data, file_writemode), and open it: reader = pickle.load(file_readmode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... but I cannot see : 'triple': DictClass(17, 'subClassOf', 34)
>
> > There is **no** `'triple': DictClass(17, 'subClassOf', 34)` in your example `data`, because your example `dict data` **is invalid**!
> >     **Keys** in a `dict` have to be **unique**, you overwrite the **first** `'triple'` with the **second** `'triple'`. Maybe you want a `list` instead of a `dict`.

---

> **Question**: I cannot access to the information into the loaded data.

You get the **same** `data object` back, assing it to a `variable` to become a `instance`.

> **Note**:
>   I use in Memory `dumps/loads`, replace with `dump/load` to write/read to/from file.

This is working for me, for instance:

```
def print_data(d):
    print('data:', d)
    print('repr(data):', repr(d))
    print("data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass})?:", data == eval(repr(d), {'DictClass':DictClass}))
    print('\n')

data = {'triple': DictClass(17, 'subClassOf', 34), 'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
print_data(data)

#pickle.dump( data, open( fname, "wb" ) )
data_pickeld = pickle.dumps( data )

#data_unpickeld = pickle.load(open(fname, 'rb'))
data_unpickeld = pickle.loads( data_pickeld)

print_data(data_unpickeld)
```

> **Output**:
>   data: {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
>   repr(data): {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
>   data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass})?: True
>
> data: {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
>   repr(data): {'triple': DictClass(22, 'subClassOf', 44)}
>   data == eval(repr(data), {'DictClass':DictClass})?: True

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Yes, you're right here, but I cannot see : 'triple': DictClass(17, 'subClassOf', 34)

Comment: Thank you, so, I understood my problem!